# Can Azure Graph be used in .Net Core 2.0 yet?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a .Net Core 2.0 Web App that authenticates a user via `ADAL` and then adds/edits users in the tenant via Microsoft Graph. I'd like to make this App work with AAD B2C scenarios where this app manages all child tenants and their contents.

This seems to be possible only with Azure AD Graph. But the only libraries I managed to find don't seem to work with .Net Core.

Am I bad at searching or is applying the scenario impossible at this moment?

Comment: I was talking about a specific link inside the question. Here's a Github repo I was talking about https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore/tree/aspnet_core_2_0

Comment: Are you sure this app works in B2C scenarios? It seems to only work with one chosen tenant, where I'd like my app to manage the contents of all b2c child tenants.

Comment: That app also doesn't invoke the graph.

Comment: That's correct, my apologies. I thought it does. I personally haven't used b2c. But I came across one post which reflected that currently there is no support for 2.0.

Comment: do you mean 'ADAL' not ASAL?  And sp error with moment, fyi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This sample project](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-GraphAPI-DotNet) interacts with Azure AD Graph via HTTP Rest calls which is obviously supported in .net core 2.0.  You can perform CRUD operations on users.

Managing the rest of B2C will come with Microsoft Graph which is not available yet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

There is a fork of this project which targets .NET Core 3.0.

https://github.com/HighViewSoftware/B2C-GraphAPI-DotNet/tree/core